# iOS Change icon in the search bar

Tags: ios, uikit, icons, uisearchbar

I'm trying to customize a search bar.  I've figured out how to change the background and the text box within the search bar, but I can't find a way to change the icon that is default in the bar (the magnify glass icon).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Open-source](https://gist.github.com/304457) is your friend (just like cocoa is, huh):

```
- (void)setSearchIconToFavicon {
  // Really a UISearchBarTextField, but the header is private.
  UITextField *searchField = nil;
  for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
      searchField = (UITextField *)subview;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (searchField) {  
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"favicon.png"];
    UIImageView *iView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    searchField.leftView = iView;
    [iView release];
  }  
}
```

Since iOS 5.0:

```
[self.testSearchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"favicon.png"]
            forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch
                       state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: in iOS 7, you should do `for (UIView *subview in [[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews])` because there is an intermediary view now

Comment: @Aurelien Porte, from iOs 5 you should use an official method instead: `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)iconImage forSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon state:(UIControlState)state` Doesn't it work for you ?

Comment: Well not really, I want to put a view, not an image. In my case, precisely, a UIActivityIndicatorView. But I agree that my previous comment didn't take into account the original question. My bad!

Comment: Anyone knows the image size that I need to use to replace, for example, the search icon image? I am using an image = 64x64 px and an image@2x = 128x128 but it is smaller than the original one.

Comment: @EduardoUrso I found the size of the search icon to be 13 by 13 points using Xcode Debug View Hierarchy mode

Answer (score 2):

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "tempUser")!,
                forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, 
                           state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Swift 3: `searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "tempUser"), for: .search, state: .normal)`