# Customize searchbar searchIcon

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar

I am customizing my search bar with this but it is not showing any image. It remove its default image as well.

```
UITextField *searchField = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in [[workLocationSearchBar.subviews lastObject] subviews]) {
         NSLog(@"hey");
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            searchField = (UITextField *)subview;
            NSLog(@"inside");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (searchField) {
        UIView *searchIcon = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"]];
        if ([searchIcon isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {

        }
        NSLog(@"aye");
        searchField.rightView = searchIcon;
        searchField.leftView=searchIcon;

    }
```

Comment: Please checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794552/ios-change-icon-in-the-search-bar

Comment: You are allocating UIView instead of UIImageView.Please make the changes and try it.

Comment: yes may be you are right...but I haven't try this because I got another way to doing this...There is method available to change SearchBar Icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
[workLocationSearchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_NAME"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```